# Overriding beans in Java-based spring configuration hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Let's assume we have an application that can be customized for some customers. The application is using Java-based spring configuration (a.k.a. Java config) for dependency injection. The application consists of modules and their submodules. Each module and submodule has its own `@Configuration` class which is imported by parent configuration using `@Import`. This creates the following hierarchy:

```
                MainConfig
          ----------+----------------   ....
          |                         |
    ModuleAConfig               ModuleBConfig
      |--------------------|
      |                    |
    SubModuleA1Config    SubModuleA2Config
```

For example `ModuleAConfig` looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import({SubModuleA1Config.class, SubModuleA2Config.class})
public class ModuleAConfig {
    // some module level beans
}
```

Let's say that `SubModuleA1Config` defines bean `someBean` of type SomeBean:

```
@Configuration
public class SubModuleA1Config {
    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() { return new SomeBean(); }
}
```

Now I want to customize the application for Customer1 (C1) - I want to use `C1SomeBean` (extending `SomeBean`) instead of `SomeBean` as `someBean`.

How can I achieve this with minimum duplication?

One of my ideas was to prepare alternative hierarchy with `C1Config` inheriting from `MainConfig`, `C1ModuleAConfig` from `ModuleAConfig` and `C1SubModuleA1Config` from `SubModuleA1Config`. `C1SubModuleA1Config` would override `someBean()` method returning `C1SomeBean`. Unfortunately with Spring 4.0.6 I get something like:

```
   Overriding bean definition for bean 'someBean': replacing [someBean defined in class C1SubmoduleA1Config] with [someBean defined in class SubModuleA1Config]
```

and indeed `SomeBean` class is returned from context instead of `C1SomeBean`. This is clearly not what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that you cannot override `@Import` extending configuration classes.

If you want to select which imports to use at runtime, you could use a `@ImportSelector` instead.

However, `@Configuration` classes are not more that spring (scoped) managed factories so as you already have a factory method for someBean you don't need to go even further:

```
@Configuration
public class SubModuleA1Config {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public SomeBean someBean() {
      String customerProperty = env.getProperty("customer");
      if ("C1".equals(customerProperty))  
        return new C1SomeBean();

      return new SomeBean(); 

   }
}
```

**Update**

Using a ImportSelector:

```
class CustomerImportSelector implements ImportSelector, EnvironmentAware {

    private static final String PACKAGE = "org.example.config";
    private static final String CONFIG_CLASS = "SubModuleConfig";

    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public String[] selectImports(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata) {
        String customer = env.getProperty("customer");
        return new String[] { PACKAGE +  "." + customer + "." + CONFIG_CLASS };
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.env = environment;
    }
}

@Configuration
@Import(CustomerImportSelector.class) 
public class ModuleAConfig {
    // some module level beans
}
```

However, as every customer has a a separate package, consider also using `@ComponentScan`. This will pick the configuration class present and don't need a extra configuration property.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.example.customer")
public class SubModuleA1Config {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerFactory customerFactory;

    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        return customerFactory.someBean();
   }
}

public interface CustomerFactory {
    SomeBean someBean();
}

@Component
public class C1CustomerFactory implements CustomerFactory {

    @Override
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        return new C1SomeBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to have customer-specific configuration in one place rather being scattered around all various configuration classes. Moreover, if there are more than 3 customers such a code does not look well. Third argument against is that each package I deliver has to have all code for all customers (unless I use reflections which makes the solution even uglier). I would like to deliver only core+C1 code to Customer1. But `@ImportSelector` might be useful in achieving such modularization. How would you apply it to get the result? There are very few examples on using it.

Comment: Regarding the import selector I see the idea but IMHO I would still have a problem of inheritance in configuration classes and non-customer bean overriding customer one. Probably better idea would be to implement `DeferredImportSelector` to execute import at the end, when non-customer configuration is already loaded. This way customer configuration will override non-customer one. Regarding the "factory solution" it works if I have well defined set of beans that can be overridden. In my case it is true. Thus accepting the answer. One fix: `@Component public class C1CustomerFactory ...`

Comment: @DawidPytel Oh! thanx for fix. Note that is legal to extend and override bean methods in a Configuration class. The problem is that imports from super classes will be parsed too.